# png loading in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I am writing a simple game in python, and I need to load an image from a  bmp/png file and draw it to the screen. 
The important part of my code looks like this:

```
temp = pygame.image.load("debris.bmp").convert()
temp.convert_alpha()
temp.blit(screen, (250,250))
pygame.display.flip()
fps.tick(20)
```

So I expect a small brick to appear on screen. This does not happen. I made it to draw a small graphic primitive immediately after the blit, and that appears to work. This indicates that I am not drawing over it, and that the display.flip() is working well. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any reason you're converting `temp` twice? You might as well just do `pygame.image.load("debris.bmp").convert_alpha()`.

Comment: that ran, but it didnt fix the issue which is that the image wont appear

Answer (score 0):

well, one reason it might not be working is how you 'blit' your image to the screen, if your pygame window is named 'screen' then it would be like this

```
screen.blit(img, (coord1, coord2))
```

like that

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late maybe but...

You are trying to blit the screen on your temp.

Change the line:

```
temp.blit(screen, (250,250))
```

to:

```
screen.blit(temp, (250,250))
```